# Как ограничить пользователей телегам бота? Python

Tags: python, telegram-bot

Есть телеграм чат с 100 участниками.
Есть бот, который отвечает на вопросы и дает инструкции.

Хочу сделать так, что бы ботом могли пользоваться Лишь те, кто в данный момент состоит в этом чате

Т.е нужно организовать проверку. Если пользователь отправивший сообщение боту, не состоит в списке участников чата - false или true

Бот должен динамически проверять наличие пользователя в чате. Не желателен вариант с внешними БД, хочу что бы бот создавал переменную со списком юзеров из Конкретного чата, и прогонял id того кто пишет через список в этой переменной

Сам я ПХПшнк и мне сложно реализовать этот функционал на Python't :/

Так же искренне буду рад ссылкам на RU источники. Где описана реализация данного функционала

Answer (score 0):

```
messages.getFullChat
```

Возвращает полную информацию о чате по его ID

сыль: https://core.telegram.org/methods

Comment: а какой модуль импортировать?

Comment: я почему-то подумал что вы используете telegram-bot-api. Во всяком случае если вы ещё не определились с библиотекой работы с телеграм, советую воспользоваться асинхронной библиотекой AIOgram документации на русском языке почти нет, но есть рус сообщество в том же телеграмме - https://t.me/aiogram_ru